# mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'xpto'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: php, python, mysql, mysql-python

I have an issue when I try to access to a mysql server (MariaDB v10.1.37 ) using the python *mysql.connector* version 8.0.15.
I am trying to read data from my database, but I am getting an error when I try to connect to mysql server.
The code of python script is:

```
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import errorcode

mysql_config = {
    'user':'xpto',
    'password':'1234',
    'host':'127.0.0.1', # I tried too 'localhost'
    'port':3306,        # I tried too '3306'
    'database':'manta'
}
print(mysql.connector.__version__)
conn = mysql.connector.connect(**mysql_config)
conn.close()
```

And the error that I am getting is:

> mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1045 (28000): Access denied
>   for user 'xpto'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

So I started debug the code.

To check if my mysql is running:

- on shell, I executed 'mysql -u xpto -p1234' to enter on server and wrote on my db,
- I executed without any error a php script on lampp. The script create a connection with mysqli and write on DB.
  By phpAdmin and shell I checked this written.

I check quickly with telnet and netstat that mysql port is 3306.

The privileges of my user are:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for xpto@localhost                                                                                                              |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'xpto'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*F1D0B735317D750FFFFD3FE51E571EFBF4FFFF1D' WITH GRANT OPTION |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Another approach to write on my db through a script python, was execute a subprocess:

```
from subprocess import Popen, STDOUT

p = Popen(["mysql", "-u", "xpto", "-p1234"],
          stdin=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
p.communicate(b"exit")
if p.returncode != 0:
    print('incorrect password')
```

I executed this script without any problem.

Another approach was to change the permissions of my python script to 777 but error stills.

More information:
I run my php script on /opt/lampp/htdocs/ context and the python script on ~/Desktop context.

Question:
So, I try to understand why I cannot to connect to mysql server using the mysql.connector.
Why the error is happening? I am passing the correct user and password.
Please, can you help me to understand why the issue happens?

Comment: I hope that `F1D0B735317D750FFFFD3FE51E571EFBF4FFFF1D` isn't your actual password. Just wanna make sure you didn't spill your beans.

Comment: What SQL server are you runinng, MySQL or MariaDB? Just in case that matters.

Comment: Torxed, thanks for your attention.
No. That hash isn't my actual password :) but thanks.

Well, I am using MariaDB, version 10.1.37.

Comment: My Flask backend was also making a seamless connection with the MySQL server until yesterday. Today, when I switched on my laptop, it has stopped working :/